# How can I create a button inside an infowindow in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I really need some help guys!!!!
How can I create a button inside an infowindow in google maps?
The infowindow contains data from a database.I have tried creating a button or a link inside the infowindow(infowincontent) but wasn't successful.
Thanks in advance

here is the code for creating the markers

```
    <script>
     function initialize() {


        initMap();
        initAutocomplete();


        }
      function initAutocomplete() {


        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


                // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction  and     retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }



          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
           if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
             return;
             }
            var icon = {
             url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
             title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
               bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }

        function initMap() {

         var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({   polylineOptions: { strokeColor: "#075e54" } });
         directionsDisplay.setOptions({ suppressMarkers: true });



        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-1.2921,36.8219),
          zoom: 14
        });


          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);




        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


                  var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change',    onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);

       function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
         directionsService.route({
         origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    },     function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }    else {
             window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }


             // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
            downloadUrl('control.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
               var superfuel = markerElem.getAttribute('superfuel');
               var diesel = markerElem.getAttribute('diesel');
                     var shop = markerElem.getAttribute('shop');
               var service = markerElem.getAttribute('service');
               var air = markerElem.getAttribute('air');


               var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              infowincontent.id = 'sometoom';
              infowincontent.style.background="#ffffff";
              var contentString = "<a href='#' onclick='openNew();'>Click here to open new infowindow!</a>";
              infowincontent.style.padding="20px";
              infowincontent.style.textAlign = 'left';











              var strong = document.createElement('strong');

              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));


              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.style.color="#000000";

              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));


                         var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = superfuel
               text.style.color="#136ad5";



              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                         var text = document.createElement('text');
                                 text.style.color="#136ad5";



              text.textContent = diesel
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                             var text = document.createElement('text');
                               text.style.color="#000000";

               text.textContent = shop
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                                 var text = document.createElement('text');
                                                   text.style.color="#000000";

              text.textContent = service
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));






                                 var text = document.createElement('text');
                                                   text.style.color="#000000";

               text.textContent = air
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
               infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));






















  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon:'pictures/huu.png',


              });





               marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
               });

             });
           });




        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
         var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
             callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD-4hkK5MZ4Svgyf611MqiKYF8&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the html code you prefer for infowindows this is a link but you can use all the tag element or customize the link with css

```
  var myContentString = 
            '<div id="your_id" style="your_style...."><a href="your_link">' +
            'My link  Text comes here' + 
            '</a></div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: myContentString,
            maxWidth: 600
        });
```

Comment: what do mean with dosen't work ... you have error ? .. .. explain better... in your code  you not use infoWindow .. you just declare it